# label.Text = ComboBox.SelectedText(); always null?

Tags: c#, combobox

I am making an application that has some options in drop-down menus that get populated from the App.Config file. I was testing a reset function when the program stopped doing the reset. My code for Form1 is below:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeDropDownMenu();
}

private void InitializeDropDownMenu()
{
    //Populate all the menus from app.config
    foreach (string s in Properties.Settings.Default.Box1Contents)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }

    foreach (string s in Properties.Settings.Default.Box2Contents)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(s);
    }

    foreach (string s in Properties.Settings.Default.Box3Contents)
    {
        comboBox3.Items.Add(s);
    }

    //Controls for drop down menus
    this.Controls.Add(comboBox1);
    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged +=
        new System.EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);

    this.Controls.Add(comboBox2);
    comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged +=
        new System.EventHandler(comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);

    this.Controls.Add(comboBox3);
    comboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged +=
        new System.EventHandler(comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged);

    //Begin Program with all dDMenus enabled.
    comboBox1.Enabled = true;
    comboBox2.Enabled = true;
    comboBox3.Enabled = true;
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
        "Change Viewer to: \r\n" + comboBox1.Text + "\r\n\r\n" + "Confirm?",
        "Menu",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        label3.Text = comboBox1.SelectedText;
    }
    else if( result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        comboBox1.ResetText();
    }
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
    "Change Viewer to: \r\n" + comboBox2.Text + "\r\n\r\n" + "Confirm?",
    "Menu",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        label3.Text = comboBox2.SelectedText;
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        comboBox2.ResetText();
    }
}

private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
    "Change Viewer to: \r\n" + comboBox3.Text + "\r\n\r\n" + "Confirm?",
    "Menu",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        label3.Text = comboBox3.SelectedText;
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        comboBox3.ResetText();
    }
}

private void ResetApp()
{
    comboBox1.ResetText();
    comboBox2.ResetText();
    comboBox3.ResetText();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ResetApp();
    label3.Text = "ResetApp Ran";
}
```

Any ideas as to why label3 is always set to null, and why when reset is clicked the ComboBoxes aren't being reset to blanks anymore?

Thank you for your help,

-Arthur

EDIT* I will use Items.Clear(); and then just call InitializeDropDownMenu() in the reset function. Should work for my intended use. Thank you all.

Comment: For clearing the comboBox just use : `comboBox1.Items.Clear();` and in your if statements, instead of using `else if`, just use `else`

Comment: What is the result if you use use SelectedValue for setting label text?

Comment: Items.Clear() will make it have to re-initialize the values inside it, the end goal of the program will be to make selections based on on an input and then reset for another input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in use of `SelectedText`. The `SelectedText`property "Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox".

Instead try to use the `SelectedItem` property.

```
label1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: This fixed the label update, Thank you! but ResetApp() still does not put the comboboxes back to an empty state

Comment: @ArthurAznive use `comboBox1.Items.Clear();` in your `ResetApp()` method.